# What ist the difference between using @Annotation and [Annotation] in Kotlin?

Tags: annotations, kotlin

For Example

```
class LoggingService [Inject] (protected val logger: Logger)

class LoggingService @Inject (protected val logger: Logger)
```

I haven't found anything in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[Annotation]` syntax was supported in early preview versions of Kotlin. It does not exist in Kotlin 1.0 or newer.

Answer (score 3):

[Annotation Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) documents this.

> If you have multiple annotations with the same target, you can avoid repeating the target by adding brackets after the target and putting all the annotations inside the brackets

Of course you can do it with one annotation as well. But you need to make sure to have the target set. This it at least a `@`. So it would be `@Inject` or `@[Inject]`, or with several annotations `@[Inject SomeScope]`.